# input text and submit elements at same height

Tags: html, css

I simply want a "flat" input text field and submit button at the same height.

HTML:

```
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input text" id="name-check" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="query!" />
    </form>
```

CSS - what I hoped would work (ugly values so you see the effect):

```
    input {
        border:0 none;
        background-color:#f00;
        height:300px;
    }
```

The result is that the input text field is about 1 pixel taller at top and bottom than the submit button (current chrome, ie, firefox on windows 7).

How can this be solved (cross-browser)?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjL45mz2/)

I wouldn't understand why I would need [such a complex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238441/problems-with-setting-input-text-and-input-submit-at-same-height?rq=1)...

Comment: this question asked before on same day..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `box-sizing:border-box;` to your input css that will do the trick. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/pjL45mz2/1/)

Comment: Is it just my eyes that still detect a 1px difference between the two? (*i'm using safari 6.15*)

Comment: try this `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */ -moz-box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: @TJ what if you add `border:1px solid #c6c6c6;` just for visual. you see the width same?

Comment: This one is it for my configuration! And the fastest one ;-) Thanks!

Comment: [can you see it?](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/pjL45mz2/3/) 0__0

Answer (score 0):

Use the below css.

CSS:

```
input {
 border:none;
background-color:#f00;
height:300px;
outline:none; //Add the below css
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
```

}
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/pjL45mz2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could put both the controls in one container with height 300px and then have height:100% for input element

Answer (score -1):

add box-sizing: border-box; CSS to input. this will solve your problem

```
input {
        border:0 none;
        background-color:#f00;
        height:300px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
       }
```

Comment: **is this a comments **?

Comment: No . unknowingly added tat to bold.

Comment: Downvoter mind to explain for downvoting?

Comment: `border:0 none;` `border:0;`  just fine and you don't need to add them if you use `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: I just showed adding the required CSS to his CSS block.